# ZXing to read 10 qr codes a second rotating on screen

Tags: zxing

I have a stream of qr codes rotating at 10 qr codes a second. I am using zxing lib to read the same but I am not able to achieve the desired result.

I have modified the zxing lib front end to provide more control over autofocus interval but I am facing it difficult to fix the focus and continue reading qr codes at 10 codes a second. Please help.